# Image height bigger than 568

Tags: ios, height, scrollview

I have to put one image in my View Controller
But the height of this image is bigger than the view..
So I put a Scroll View..
But how I add constraints to looks like good in all iPhones sizes?

ps: I have to put Scroll View because I need to zoom the image.

Sorry for my bad english..

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in a scroll view just set the fill to 'aspect fill' to preserve your aspect ratio and not distort the image. Then set the image view constraints to '0' for all 4 sides of your containing view.

Comment: Screen shot would be nice also 

Comment: could you add a screen shot of a device or running on the simulator of the image along with a description of what is not right with it.

Comment: it also looks like you may have some conflicting constraints.